# VBA conditional formatting depending metric type

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I've been trying to create a VBA code that will apply automatically proper conditonal formatting for indicators results depending if they are ascending or descending. 
Tried to use vlookup to search for indicator code in table and output value= Descending/Ascending and assign only to that indicator proper conditional formatting not whole column.

So if we are looking for cell E2 in table Sheets("Formulas").Range(A:N) and we find it with value Descending and since "result" isn`t equal ascdes then I would want to code create Conditional Formatting for descending indicator in cell $AA$2. This would nee to happen for all indicators from range.

I've only managed to create below code that creates descending conditional formatting but for all cells in column AA instead of only AA2.

Indicators are mixed so putting manually CF will take a lot of time and  if someone will sort indicators A-Z and save he will have to only run macro that will fix CF instead of reversing changes of sorting.

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()

Dim code As Range 'searched values
Dim ascdes As String 'variable that indicates values are ascending or descending
Dim table As Range 'table where we check if code is ascending or descending
Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition, cond3 As FormatCondition
Dim rg As Range
Dim result As String

Set rg = Range("$AA$2:$AA$300")

'clear any existing conditional formatting
rg.FormatConditions.Delete

'vlookup conditions
Set code = Range("E2")
Set table = Sheets("Formulas").Range("A:N")

'holds value ascendat for comparison purposes
rosmal = Sheets("Formulas").Range("O2")

result= Application.VLookup(code, table, 14, 0)

If result = ascdes Then

'define the rule for each conditional format
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreaterEqual, "=$Q2") 'Green
Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "=$O2", "=$P2") 'Amber
Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLessEqual, "=$N2") 'Red

'define the format applied for each conditional format
With cond1
.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'vbGreen
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

With cond2
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'vbYellow
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

With cond3
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'vbRed
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

Else

    'define the rule for each conditional format
Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreaterEqual, "=$N2") 'Red
Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "=$O2", "=$P2") 'Amber
Set cond3 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLessEqual, "=$Q2") 'Amber

'define the format applied for each conditional format
With cond1
.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'vbGreen
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

With cond2
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'vbYellow
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

With cond3
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'vbRed
.Font.Color = vbBlack
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Almost forgot used excel version is 2013 and cannot install any external addons.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue by using creating variable and use it in Cells to move across spreadsheet. Also added do while loop which increases varaible value untill it reaches certain value.